# adobe flex: 2 projects with same class, can i share that class between the two projects?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

i have several flash projects and i have common classes. is there a way to share these classes between the project so i won't need to copy it to all the project when ever i modify something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flex Builder, right click on the project and choose properties.  In the Flex Build Path section choose Add Folder... and pick the project you want to reference then the /src folder (so ${DOCUMENTS}//src).  This will allow one project to use the classes in another project.  However be careful as this will slow down compile times.  Probably a better idea to build a library where you have dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

in adobe flex/flash builder when i add a new folder, i can click on advanced and then i can choose to which folder, this folder will be linked. by doing so i can share directories between several projects.